# Is there any free PHP IDE that offers these features?

Tags: php, ide

- Written in c++
- Highlighter php, html, css, javascript
- Easy Code Navigation
- Hinting
- Remote and Local Project Development
- FTP
- Code collapsing (folding)
- Intelligent Auto-complete
- Code completion

Optional:
 - Debugging

These are the features im looking for ide that is NOT written in java AND free.

Comment: Why do you care which language your IDE is written in?

Comment: Why does it need to be free? If you're spending hours and hours using your IDE, surely a modest license fee would be worth the investment. My IDE (textmate, does not meet your specific requirements) but it's only $40 or so.

Comment: What platform are you developing on? (Not for, *on*)

Comment: I've used both Netbeans and Eclipse for PHP, and they are awesome :)
  Not only that, they are portable (thanks to the JVM) and so you won't have to re-learn how to use the IDE when you switch O/S (something I do quite often)

Comment: I'd advise spending the $49 for PhpStorm.

Comment: if you are asking for an ide it has a debugger as for the term [ide](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/IDE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPDesigner 7 is really fast.  It has everything you are looking for, except IT'S NOT FREE, but it's really worth the money.

I use it on old machines, where others are really unusable.  It opens files very quickly and runs smoothly.

It also has source code navigator (shows you an index of the PHP functions, classes, methods and variables you have defined in your current file), and lets you jump from a function call to the definition with Ctrl+click, just like NetBeans and the big ones.  It only lacks code collapsing.

Other that I used in the past:  Dev-PHP.  Written in Delphi, but very fast also.  I found some bugs so I left it, but other users in my company didn't had those bugs, so it was probably my installation only... try it yourself.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/devphp/

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite funny, I think you are talking about an on demand software :). Well i think [this](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) is almost what you are looking for, unless it's written in JAVA. Written in JAVA doesn't mean u gonna program in JAVA.

Comment: He's looking for a PHP IDE.  I think he knows that an IDE written in Java isn't necessarily only for programming in Java.  I can tell you one reason to avoid an IDE written in Java.  The UI tends to be sluggish.

Comment: @George I don't know why people still perpetuate the myth that Java is slow. Java is quite fast actually, as fast or faster than C++ most of the times.

Comment: @NullUserException  I'm speaking from personal experience with the Zend IDE (5.x) and Eclipse.  I gave up on both and learned VIM.

Comment: @George That's like comparing an Audi with a Yugo

Comment: @NullUserException Nah, more like comparing a Lincoln to an Ariel Atom.  Bear in mind that there are VIM emulations in various editors.  It's no Yugo.

Comment: java is slow for my old laptop. i have brand new laptop it is 3 months old and java is fast so i need something that gonna be fast on both

Comment: @NullUserException not true, java always runs slower on motern(read x64) linux machines as it sous not have a x64 vm, if your java code is faster as c++ code you do not code right in c++.
plus software in a vm is per definition slower as naively compiled software

Comment: @borrel 64-bits doesn't give you any speed advantage, it just give you (possibly) more memory. *"if your java code is faster as c++ code you do not code right in c++"* Yes, a well written C++ program will beat Java every time. **But** memory allocation and garbage collection is very hard to code right. For the most part Java will be able to handle it more efficiently than the vast majority of C++ programmers.

Comment: @NullUserException true but stating that java is faster is just plain wrong

Answer (score 1):

This won't meet all your requirements, but I doubt you'll find anything for free that will.

[Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit)

It has syntax highlighting and auto complete for the languages you mentioned and a few more.  It also provides code folding and may fill your needs for remote/local project management. As for code navigation, it provides VI/Emacs emulation, at the very least.

I haven't tried it, but I have been meaning to do so.  Now that [Eric C C](https://stackoverflow.com/users/401327/) has [reminded in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap/3327874#3327874), I'm going to download it and finally give it a try.  Looking forward to trying the VI emulation.

Comment: @chanchal1987 I like it so far.  I may actually find myself buying the IDE at some point.  Until then, I'm going to put the editor through the paces.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try **[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)**?

Notepad++ is a free (as in "free speech" and also as in "free beer") source code editor and Notepad replacement that supports several languages. Running in the MS Windows environment, its use is governed by GPL License.

I think it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Every features you want, like highlighter, easy code navigation, auto complete, debugging, ftp etc. are available in Notepad++.

Comment: Notepad++ is a great text editor, which I use instead of notepad on Windows. I didn't know it supported debugging or auto complete.  Are they plugins not included by default? That said, I notice now that it has a plugin for FTP. That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 0):

I use geany for a long time. It is written in C and fast enough. Addons helps to have autocomplete, code navigation, etc functionality.